# C# best way to get a List with instance of childrin classes from parent class

Tags: c#

I got A Parents Class Item and some children Classes which inheritance from them like Sword, Shild and so on.
I now want to write a function which return one random item something like this.

```
int randomNumber = random()
return ItemList[randomNumber]
```

But how looks an elegant way to fill the ItemList ? Is there a way to fill the ItemList without x lines of

```
itemlist.append(new Sword);
itemList.append(new Shild);
itemList.append(new boots);
```

...
and so one ?

Comment: The close vote is nonsensical, there is no bug that needs debugging.

Comment: You could use a loop, perhaps. It depends, we don't know where you are getting this data from to populate your list

Comment: Try following :             string[] items = { "sword", "shield", "boots" };
            Random rand = new Random();
            string[] random = Enumerable.Range(0, 100).Select(x => items[rand.Next(items.Length)]).ToArray();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a collection initializer to simplify it a bit:

```
itemList = new List<ParentClass>{
    new Sword(),
    new Shield(),
    new Boots()
};
```

If the objects need some initial values as well, you can combine it with object initializers

```
itemList = new List<ParentClass>{
    new Sword { Length = 50, Name = "Excalibur" },
    new Shield { Strength = 95 },
    new Boots { Size = 45 }
};
```

Do never create a `Random` object in a tight loop. It initializes itself with the current time. Since the PC clock ticks rather slowly, it might then return the same random number several times in a row. better make it a static readonly object at class level.

```
private static readonly Random random = new Random();
```

Then you can get an index in the range of the list with

```
int index = random.Next(itemList.Count);
var gameObject = itemList[index];
```